# Question of analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

If we have a function $f$ which is analytic inside (but not on) the unit disc, can $f$ have infinitely many zeroes inside the unit disc? I feel like it would break some holy law if it did, but can't quite prove it.

Consider $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(n)z^n$
Where $\mu$ is the mobius function.

I was just wondering if it were possible for $f$ to oscillate signs infinitely often as $z\to 1^-$ along the real line. It seemes very unlikely that a function whose coefficients are all $\pm1$  could act so uncourteously, but nonetheless it is perhaps possible.

Comment: No problem. You can even have bounded functions that are holomorphic on the open unit disk and have infinitely many zeros. Look at Blaschke products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is quite possible; for example, if you choose a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of points in the unit disc for which

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (1 - |a_n|) < \infty$$ and define the [Blaschke product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product)

$$f(z) = \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{|a_n|}{a_n} \frac{a_n - z}{1 - \overline{a_n} z}$$

then this converges to an analytic (and $H^{\infty})$ function on the unit disc with zeros precisely at $\{a_n\}$ (counting multiplicity).

Note that the sum condition is a sort of "correction" for the fact that the set of zeros could have an accumulation point on the boundary now.